# How to interpret “Mein Sohn, was birgst du so bang dein Gesicht?”

Tags: grammar-identification, interrogative

In Schubert’s song [Erlkönig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlk%C3%B6nig_(Goethe)), (written by Goethe), there is a line:

> Mein Sohn, was birgst du so bang dein Gesicht?"

I see it translated into

> My son, why do you hide your face in fear?

I can't exactly understand it. I would agree if it were one of the following:

> Warum birgst du so bang dein Gesicht?
>
> Von was [or is it *wasvon*?] birgst du so bang dein Gesicht?

But here *was* seems to be the object word of *birgst,* and so is *dein Gesicht.* Which is the object of the verb *birgst?* And how do we interpret *was* here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your sentence

> Was birgst du so bang dein Gesicht

is a token of a German idiom which can be found pretty often in literatur from the older days. But the idiom can still be heared today even in everyday language.

The *was* here is not used in the otherwise usual sense of asking for an object of a verb as in

> Was isst du da? - Eine Banane, das siehst du doch!

In your sentence, the *was* has a different meaning. See the following examples:

> Was bohrst du dir dauernd in der Nase?
>
> Was nestelst du immer an deinem Regenschirm herum?
>
> Was bummelst du schon wieder so rum?
>
> Was sendet der Trump da immer diese Twitter-Nachrichten, hat er nichts besseres zu tun?
>
> Was regnet es heute schon wieder ohne Unterlass?

In all these cases, the "was" is used as a shorter synonym for

> Warum nur...
>
> Warum bloß...
>
> Warum um Himmels willen...

which is like *warum* plus disapprobation of the behaviour or phenomenon in focus.

**Bonus fact**

An interesting case is

> Was isst du denn?

Here, the *was* could be read as asking for an object; or it could be interpreted as

> Warum isst du denn schon wieder?

as in

> Was isst du denn schon wieder eine Banane? Du hast doch heute schon drei gegessen!

Things depend here simply on intonation (and other means of non-verbal communication accompanying the verbal utterance).

**Is it provocative?**

In certain situation asking things like

> Was kuckst du mich so an?

can be perceived as provocative (as RoyPJ in his answer correctly noted). However, this depends more on the situation as such (in the above example the question would be provocative in most cases because asking somebody why he is looking at you is in most cases provocative independent of wording). But there are also cases where a *was*-disapprobation would not be provocative but simply carry the message of emotional involvement:

> Was regnet es heute nur den ganzen Tag!
>
> Was würde ich gerne nochmals nach Venedig fahren!

Oh. The last one even shows that *was* may also replace *wie*, since *warum nur* is not what the person speaking intends to say; and that it also may be used to express a wish, not only dissaproval.

Comment: I like your banana example. The difference of was (was) and was (warum) could also be shown in your nose-picking example: „Was bohrst du dir dauernd in der Nase“ versus „Nach was bohrst du dir dauernd in der Nase“, where the answer could be „Weil sie juckt“ or „Nach diesem großen grünen Popel hier, schau mal!“

Answer (score 4):

I will try to wrap this up from the start:

> Mein Sohn birgt sein Gesicht.
>   Subjekt - Verb - Objekt

I think what confused you was this:

> *Was* birgt mein Sohn? 
>   Sein Gesicht.

*Was* can work as a substitution for *warum* in many cases, although it is barely used. The standard example is

> Was schaust du mich so an?

I would advise you not to use this construction, since

- it is incorrect in some cases
- it is mostly perceived as bad style or provoking
- *warum* always works

Of course this was all a bit different in the time of Goethe and it was in no way bad style of him to use it.

To conclude:

> Mein Sohn birgt so bang das Gesicht. 
>   Subjekt - Verb - Adjektiv -  Objekt
>
> Warum birgst du so bang das Gesicht?

And with explicit addressing to his son:

> Mein Sohn, warum birgst du so bang das Gesicht? 
>   Mein Sohn, was birgst du so bang das Gesicht?